# Laravel and Lumen ACL with Shared Codebase

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles, lumen

I have two separate projects:

1. Admin (Laravel 5.4)
2. API   (Lumen 5.4)

with Shared Codebase (database, models...)

In my Admin project I use `spatie/laravel-permission`, but this package is not available for Lumen i.e. When I try to install package in my Lumen project (API) I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class path.storage does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:681 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): ReflectionClass->__construct('path.storage') #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(565): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('path.storage') #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(208): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('path.storage') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(105): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('path.storage') #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(800): app('path.storage') #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/view.php(31): storage_path('framework/views') #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(575): require('/var/www/html/v...') #7 /var/www/html/ in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 681
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class path.storage does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:681 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): ReflectionClass->__construct('path.storage') #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(565): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('path.storage') #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(208): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('path.storage') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(105): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('path.storage') #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(800): app('path.storage') #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/view.php(31): storage_path('framework/views') #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Appli in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 681

Where is the problem? Can I use this package in Lumen? 
Or could you suggest me some other package for Role & Permission work in Laravel and Lumen.

Comment: Can i ask you why do you have 2 seperate projects if you share the codebase?

Comment: Because Lumen has better performance for API, and I will have many users that will used API. Other part is Admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that **spatie/laravel-permission** repository does not support Lumen

try to see if this may be for you
http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.2/acl